# Determining minimum probability for a standardised variable using the Chebyshev inequality

Tags: self-study, distributions, inequality

> A report on rural water resources states that the nitrate level of wells in a certain groundwater system has a probability distribution
>   whose mean and standard deviation are 5.2, 2.1 ppm, respectively. 
>   From the Chebyshev inequality, determine the minimum probability that a well in this system
>   will have a nitrate level between 0.4 and 10.0 ppm.

For a standardised random variable Y corresponding to a random variable X:

> $Y = \frac{X - E\left \{ X \right \}}{\sigma\left \{ X \right \}}$

Any hints to further my attempt is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to be two different questions.  Are you asking about the question you have quoted or are you trying to ask something about your data `Y`?  If it's the latter, what are you asking?

Comment: @whuber the question I have quoted. Everything else is my attempt thus far.

Comment: I am confused because very little that follows the question seems to be related to the question.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=chebyshev+inequality for related questions.